# How to delete a row from listView with customised adapter

Tags: android, listview, android-listview

i have ListView with cusomised adapter that extends BaseAdapter. the listview items layout contains(textView, Checkbox, and imageView).

what what to do is, when the image view is clicked, the row that contains this image view should be deleted from the listView.

For an examle, if the listView contains 6 items, and user clicke the the imageView of the 4th item in the listView, the 4th row should be deleted entirly from the listview, 
and consequently, the lisview should contain 5 items and so on.

what i attempted is, in the getView() method "posted below" of the Baseadapter, i created onClickListener of the imageview, and it is as follows:

```
iv.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            parent.removeView(convertView);
            notifyDataSetChanged();
        }
    });
```

the problem is, inside the above mentioned listener, i have to set converView to final, and convertView should be assigned to value to initialise it if it null, so it can not be final,

now i do not know how to solve this issue pluse i am not sure whether or not the way i follow is a correct way to remove an item from the listView

**getView**:

```
@Override
public View getView(int position, final View convertView, final ViewGroup parent) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub


    if (convertView == null) {
        LayoutInflater layoutinflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Activity.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        convertView = layoutinflater.inflate(R.layout.list_items_layout, null);// here convertView cannot be final
    }

    final TextView tv = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.tvlist_topic);
    final CheckBox cb = (CheckBox) convertView.findViewById(R.id.cbList_hook);
    final ImageView iv = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.ivList_delete);

    tv.setText(this.arrayList.get(position));

    iv.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            parent.removeView(convertView);
            notifyDataSetChanged();
        }
    });

    return convertView;
}
```

Comment: Remove the entry from arrayList and then call `notifyDataSetChanged()` on listView.

Comment: Use `arrayList.remove(position)` and after that refresh your adapter with `notifyDataSetChanged()` in `getView()` method.

Answer (score 1):

To achieve it you have to remove the element from the dataset and call notifydatasetchanged, to reschedule a redraw of the ListView's row. What you need is the position of row you want to delete. What you could do is to tag the iv object with the position, and retrieve the tag when you press on it:

```
iv.setTag(position);
iv.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        if (v.getTag() != null) {  
           arrayList.remove((int) v.getTag);
           notifyDataSetChanged();
        }
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

To update your view, you should remove the element from your ArrayList thanks to the position and then call `notifydataSetChanged()`

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you are trying to destroy the view, however you should delete the entry in your ArrayList from which each element in your ListView is created.

```
 //assuming that the data source for your listview is called "arrayList"
 //this code should be in your getView() method

    //set the position as a tag on your view
    iv.setTag(position);

    iv.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                //retrieve the tag
                int posToRemove= (int) v.getTag();
                //remove position from your source array
                arrayList.remove(posToRemove);
                //let your adapter know that there was a change in the dataset
                notifyDataSetChanged();
            }
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

How come you made `convertView` and `parent` final ? I have a similar usecase, and in my Adapter (extending `ArrayAdapter`) I have

```
@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
}
```

Is Eclipse prompting for you to add the `final` modifier ?

EDIT: Here's how I'm doing it - hope it's the proper way, it works for me !

Listener

```
public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
  doDelete();
}
```

ListActivity

```
private void doDelete() {
  Item[] newList = new Item[_itemList.length -1];
  // ... update the Array
  itemList= newList ;
  setListAdapter(new YourAdapter(this, R.layout.list_item, _itemList));
}
```

Comment: yes eclipse prompted me to do so, when i tried to reference the convertview and the parent inside the onClicklistener

Comment: Alternatively to what other people say, you could also call `setListAdapter()` from your ListActivity with an updated `Adapter`.

Comment: You don't have to use the convertView in your Listener.

In your Listener, you should update the Array your Adapter is displaying, then update your Adapter or create a new instance of it using this updated Array. Finally, call setListAdapter().

Answer (score 0):

remove data from adapter and then call notifyDataSetChanged(). the list will refresh. Don't remove view from list.